# Fitting pmdarima auto_arima to time series with missing values

Tags: python, time-series, missing-data, arima

I have some time series data at weekly granularity, but some weeks have NaN values.

The pmdarima auto_arima documentation says that the input time series data should not contain any np.nan or np.inf values.

It looks like the R ARIMA package allows you to fit time series with missing values: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346225/fitting-arima-to-time-series-with-missing-values

I also know that passing `method='statespace'` into a `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA` model allows me to do the same: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6596

So, without having to use imputed values in my training data, what are my options if I want to use auto_arima on my time series data?

Answer (score 2):

**Interpolate the missing values**: Another approach is to interpolate the missing values in your time series. Interpolation is a technique that estimates the missing values based on the existing values in the series. There are different interpolation methods available, such as linear interpolation, spline interpolation, or seasonal interpolation. Once the missing values are interpolated, you can use the interpolated time series as input to the auto_arima function.

**Divide and conquer**: If the missing values occur in specific contiguous segments of your time series, you can divide the series into multiple segments where each segment contains continuous data without missing values. Then, you can apply the auto_arima function separately to each segment, treating them as separate time series. This way, you can fit ARIMA models to each segment individually, considering only the available data.

**Use other libraries**: If you need to handle missing values directly within the ARIMA modeling process without imputation or interpolation, you may consider using other time series forecasting libraries or packages that support missing values, such as the R ARIMA package you mentioned in your question. You can leverage the capabilities of these libraries to handle missing values during the modeling process. like Prophet https://pypi.org/project/prophet/

Remember to evaluate the impact of missing values on the quality of your forecasts. Depending on the nature and amount of missing data, imputation or interpolation may introduce biases or distort the patterns in your time series. It's important to assess the suitability of these approaches for your specific use case and consider the potential implications on the accuracy of your forecasts.